# how can i make out put of cmake to make using foreign__cc in bazel

Tags: bazel, bazel-cpp, foreign-cc

we want to run cmake . && make, I currently do

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake", "make")

cmake(
    name = "abc-lib",
    generate_args = ["-DBUILD_TESTS=OFF"],
    lib_source = "@xxx//:all_srcs",
)

make(
    name = "abc",
    lib_source = ":bca-lib",
)
```

but it does not seem to work, any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you have an error message or something. Otherwise it's pretty difficult to answer your question.